# 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed trying to sum columns and datatype is float

Tags: pandas, sum, mutable

I am tryning to sum all values in a range of columns from the third to last of several thousand columns using:

```
day3prep['D3counts'] = day3prep.sum(day3prep.iloc[:, 2:].sum(axis=1))
```

dataframe is formated as:

```
ID G1  Z1  Z2 ...ZN
0  50  13  12 ...62
1  51  62  23 ...19

dataframe with summed column:
ID G1  Z1  Z2 ...ZN D3counts
0  50  13  12 ...62 sum(Z1:ZN in row 0)
1  51  62  23 ...19 sum(Z1:ZN in row 1)
```

I've changed the NaNs to 0's. The datatype is float but I am getting the error:

```
'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: Do you mean `day3prep['D3counts'] = day3prep.iloc[:, 2:].sum(axis=1)` for sum by rows? Or `day3prep.iloc[:,2:].sum().sum()` for sum of all the elements?

Comment: I want to sum all columns from the third column to the final column. I elaborated in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need this part:

```
day3prep['D3counts'] = day3prep.iloc[:, 2:].sum(axis=1)
```

With some random numbers:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(42)
day3prep = pd.DataFrame({'ID': random.sample(range(10), 5), 'G1': random.sample(range(10), 5),
    'Z1': random.sample(range(10), 5), 'Z2': random.sample(range(10), 5), 'Z3': random.sample(range(10), 5)})

day3prep['D3counts'] = day3prep.iloc[:, 2:].sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
> day3prep


    ID  G1  Z1  Z2  Z3  D3counts
0   1   2   0   8   8        16
1   0   1   9   0   6        15
2   4   8   1   3   3         7
3   9   4   7   5   7        19
4   6   3   6   6   4        16
```

Comment: I didn't even notice I had sum twice. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! A second pair of eyes always helps :)